# How to show only last 5 rows from DataBase using foreach

Tags: php

Hi i have database table called Log,
I want to show only the last 5 rows from this dabatase .
Here my code :

php :

```
function get_log_data(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM log";
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection);

    if(!$result) //ERROR IN YOUR SQL QUERY
    return false;

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) //NO ROWS IN TABLE pages
    return false;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) // CHANGE THE RESULT TO 2 DIMMENSIONAL ARRAY
    {
        $returned_array[] = $row;
    }
    return $returned_array;
}
```

on the html :

```
$log_data = $func->get_log_data();

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%">
    <?php
        foreach($log_data as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo '<tr >';
            echo '<td class="count" style="width:20px;text-align:center;">.</td><td>'. $value['action'].' : '.$value['user'].' .</td>';
            echo '</tr >';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

i want to foreach only 5 last and no more
Thanks.

Comment: Suggest you to use `LIMIT` in query itself for that

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307224/how-to-select-the-5-latest-row-from-my-mysql

Comment: use `limit 5` and `orde by column DESC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM log order by PRIMARY_KEY DESC limit 5";
```

Using foreach

```
for($i=(count($log_data)-1); $i>=count($log_data)-5;$i++) {
    //your logic
}
```

Comment: ok i dont understand so much in stack..

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:1**

Use a **LIMIT** 5 records on your query

```
SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY yourcolumnname DESC LIMIT 5
```

**Solution:2**

Use an escaper ;)

```
$i=0;
foreach($log_data as $key=>$value)
    {
    if($i==5)
     break;
    echo '<tr >';
    echo '<td class="count" style="width:20px;text-align:center;">.</td><td>'. $value['action'].' : '.$value['user'].' .</td>';
    echo '</tr >';
$i++;

    }
```

Comment: Where's Solution 2? also he said *I want to show only the last 5 rows from this dabatase* so you are missing out the `DESC`

Comment: And a descending sorting to get the last 5.

Comment: He said "using FOREACH", not "using SQL"

Comment: @Mr.Alien, Was typing in the meantime. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @PaulDenisevich, O.O at Solution 2

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($log_data as $key=>$value)
{
   if ($i <= 5)
   {
      echo '<tr >';
      echo '<td class="count" style="width:20px;text-align:center;">.</td><td>'. $value['action'].' : '.$value['user'].' .</td>';
      echo '</tr >';
   }
   $i++;
}
```

But it's better to use LIMIT in SQL unless you want to keep that query result for something else not only for that `foreach`

Comment: It would be better to use limit here, say if OP has millions of rows and he wants to show just 5, so calling each row from the database and using 5 out of it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Then it's another question. His question was "how to ... using FOREACH" so I gave him this solution.

Comment: Correct, may be he is not aware of that, *I want to show only the last 5 rows from this dabatase*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC
```